# 2.83 Volumetric Light flickers when camera moves

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

[Volumetric light always flickers in Eevee when the camera is moving.](https://imgur.com/a/AamlR9Q)

There's also DOF, but it flickers even when it's off.
In this particular video it does not seem that horrible of an issue, but in other instances it's quite bad.
Can anyone point me to a possible source of the problem?

Comment: is it not flickering on purpose?

Comment: Have you baked the lighting?

Comment: Christopher, just did (added irradiance volume + baked indirect) - it didn't make a difference.